# do i need an html audio element to play song using web audio api

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Just started to learn web audio api.i have searched for how to load and play audio file using web audio api in Chrome.i kind of copy paste the codes here except an click event.here i want to play a song through an onClick event.But unfortunately no sound is playing.
i have some questions regarding the codes:

$ do i need an html audio element to use web audio api functionalities??

$ is there anything wrong with the code??if there is please help me to figure it out.

i am getting following errors:

**1.** it says XMLHttp can not load m.mp3 .cross origin request are only supported for HTTP

**2** uncaught ref. error: failed to execute 'send' on XMLHttpRequest..

the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mydiv{
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   border:1px solid black;
   border-radius:50%;
   background:blue;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='mydiv' onClick='play();'></div>
<script>
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var music; 

function loadSound() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "m.mp3", true); 
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer"; 
    request.onload = function() {
     context.decodeAudioData(request.response,function(buffer){
        music = buffer;

    });}
    request.send();
}


function play() {
    source = context.createBufferSource(); /
    buffer = context.createBuffer(music, true); 
    source.buffer = buffer; 
    source.connect(context.destination); 
    source.start(0); 
}


window.onload=loadSound;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a trailing `/` in `play` which is probably throwing an error (did you check your console?) also, how are you ensuring that `play` is only invoked after `request` has fired it's load event?

Comment: i removed it .still the same.I have attacede the errors i am getting with the post.pls check it out..

Comment: i didn't understadn your last question.it is the first time i am using XMLHttpRequest in my code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$ do i need an html audio element to use web audio api functionalities??**

Answer: No

**$ is there anything wrong with the code??if there is please help me to figure it out.**

For one there this `});}` In the loadSound function

And a random front slash in the play function after `source = context.createBufferSource()`

**i am getting following errors:**

**1. it says XMLHttp can not load m.mp3 .cross origin request are only supported for HTTP**

**2 uncaught ref. error: failed to execute 'send' on XMLHttpRequest..**

Are you running this off a server or your desktop? *You need to be running off a server*

---

Try this but make sure you're running it off a server with your audio file on the same server:

```
var audioBuffer;

var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();

getSound.open("GET", "m.mp3", true);


getSound.onload = function() {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSnare.response, function(buffer) {
        audioBuffer = buffer; // assign the buffer to a variable that can then be 'played'
    });


};
getSound.send()

function playSound() {

    var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    playSound.buffer = ourSound;
    playSound.connect(audioContext.destination);
    playSound.start(0)




}

window.addEventListener("mousedown", playSound);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an audio element, however it doesn't need to be attached to the DOM.

```
function play()
{
    (new Audio('m.mp3')).play();
}
```

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3L29z/) as an example.

Make sure to check out the [HTML5 audio and video guide on MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Comment: but i have tried  createOscillator prior to this example .it didn't need any audio element